# Should we rename this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, title

[how to destroy object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445365/how-to-destroy-object)

This question is a little bad for multiple reasons:

- The real question of the OP is hidden in an answer comments. If you read only the title and the body of the question, you can't know what the response is talking about.
- If you search in google or on SO, you'll find this question. But the accepted answer is not about "How to destroy an object" ? It is about "How to destroy a dialog window in Swing ?". If you want a response to the title question, you have to read all the answers.

So I wonder, should we rename this question?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it should be edited. And while there, I think:

☑ Tags should be edited
☑ Grammar should be fixed
☑ Close button should be clicked

Done, done and done!

Comment: Whats hilarious, is it has been reopened.  Course, its a "brand new" question now.

Comment: @iamkrillin Well it's now a valid question. A win for the moderation process!

Answer (score 5):

Besides just the title, the question itself is really unclear.  As you noted, the accepted answer had to notice a comment on another answer to figure out the context for the question.  I think I've managed to suss out all the context needed to make the question clear.  I've edited the question to include the context given by the comment, but feel free to make additional improvements.

This makes the more upvoted answers (which actually solve the underlying question) more relevant at the cost of the other general garbage collector answers being a bit out of place.  But I think the edit makes both the question and most of its answer better.